# Is Akka suitable for systems with transient network coverage?

Tags: java, scala, akka

Is Akka suitable to use in a system where nodes are expected to be moving in and out of wifi coverage? What aspects have to be considered (e.g. what transport protocols are preferred)?

Comment: What would your messaging semantics be?

Comment: Request-reply as well as fire and forget (if possible).

Comment: No, I mean, at-most-once, at-least-once, how long would outbound messages be retained, would they overflow to disk, is there an upper bound on the messages in the outbound queue, and if so, what should happen if that limit is reached?

Comment: Sorry for not replying sooner but i had to do some reading about messaging semantics :) I think that the system could be designed to use at-least-once (which is preferred, right?). Most messages can be thrown away as nodes are disconnected (basically a new "session" will be started when a node connects/reconnects). Some messages will however have to overflow to disk, probably without an upper bound...

Comment: Then I think Akka should work :-)

Comment: Can you be more specific? Maybe give some hints on why that this will work and in what circumstances Akka would not be a good choice? (or what special configuration would be required to successfully use Akka)

Comment: Akka remote actors has your desired semantics and you can use supervisor hierarchies to handle the non-delivery errors.
You haven't really given any specifics other than that, so I can only comment on what you've said so far.

Comment: @Viktor Klang this questions has been sitting on "unasnwered" list for a while. Ironically the world's most legendary expert has already answered the question ;) Could one of you create an answer entry so we can all upvote and move on, please?

Comment: Ok @Eugene, I'll write an answer since I gather Viktor is a busy man :) If he wants to write an answer instead I will of course accept that since he is the authority in this matter.

Comment: I am trying to use a supervisor hierarchy to handle non-delivery errors, but I cannot get the actor that fails to send the message (fire and forget) to throw an exception upon the send failure. What strategy should I use to make the error lead to an exception being thrown (so that the supervisor can be notified)?

Comment: Even if you'd have guaranteed delivery, which you do not, you wouldn't have guaranteed processing either. The only way to "guarantee" is to use !!! and wait for a response.

Comment: I was thinking something along the lines of https://gist.github.com/1143971. This is of course a hack, but I think you get the intent of what I want to achieve. Don't know if the concept of a fire and forget send with timout is something that you would consider supporting, but I can see some usecases for it especially in a system with transient network coverage. It might also be that the timeout should refer to the message being processed instead of being received.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Akka **is** suitable for systems with transient network coverage. Supervisor hierarchies can be used to handle the non-delivery errors as Viktor has pointed out in the comments to the question. For more details see the conversation in the comments to the question.

To verify this I have done some testing with two computers and physically switched the network connection to one of them on and off. There were no problems with hanging sockets and messages that were queued during the outage were delivered when the connection was (physically) reestablished, just as expected.