# Does akka provide monitoring of the network connection between remote actors?

Tags: java, scala, akka

This is a follow up question to a question I posted a while ago ([Is Akka suitable for systems with transient network coverage?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6401500/49972)).

I'm wondering if there is a monitoring mechanism (a heart beat or something equivalent) available for akka actors that can be used to monitor the connection between two actors. Typically one of the actors will be supervising the other, so I guess it would be nice if this was integrated with the supervising mechanism of akka.

Answer (score 1):

There is a fault tolerance mechanism for akka. You could implement it to your needs.
I think that is more like application layer so it's not so fast as other solutions.
http://akka.io/docs/akka/1.1/scala/fault-tolerance.html

Comment: I might have phrased the question badly but the question i meant to ask is not if it can be done in the application layer, but rather if it is provided by the akka platform.